# How do i create array and put value on it - BASH script

Tags: arrays, bash

ahhh array and loops my weakest links. I was trying to create array depending on user input so

```
printf "%s\n" "how may array you want"
read value
```

after this i will ask what value user want to put on a array(this is the bit im stuck on)

```
i=1
while [ $i -le $value ]
do 
    echo "what value you want to put in array $i"
    read number
    echo $number >> array.db
    i=$(( i+1 ))
    echo 
done
```

although this method works(i think) but i'm not too sure if i'm actually creating an array and putting value to that array.

Comment: Are you trying to create an array in the shell? What is the purpose of that `array.db` file? What are you going to *do* with this array once you create it?

Comment: i just want to store value on array.db just to see if it worked or not and shell yeah no clue i don't have a clue in array.

Comment: That script will write a series of numbers one-per-line to the `array.db` file. I have no idea what you intend to do with that file though (it isn't a shell array).

Comment: the only reason i'm using array.db is because later on i want to use the value from array.db using grep

Comment: During the same script or during a later script? And how are you intending to use the file with `grep`? Using `-f`?

Comment: it will be later script so it only happens once if the user already has a value i wont ask i will only display array value so it happens later in script and yes i will using -f

Comment: Is your script here really just going to be putting single values, one-per-line, in a text file? If so do you really think that has value over just telling the person to use an editor?

Comment: This script will create an `array.db` file with one value per-line. If that's the goal then you are fine. That file is in no way an "array" or a "db" though. If that is the goal of the script then I would argue that your script is *strictly worse* then just letting the user create that file by hand in a text editor.

Comment: Im not too sure what you are trying to say but lets extend the code I'm actually working on
      Echo your username
      Read user
      printf "%s\n" "how may array you want"
      read value

      printf "%s" $user ":" $i ":" $value $' \n'  >> array.db
and later on I will grep it 
      grep -i $user array.db -s | awk -F ":" '{print $2}'

Comment: ohh i see then ok im done with this code thanks

Comment: BTW, if you wanted to store a list of values for each user, it would make more sense to have a separate file per username. More efficient to write, more efficient to read, less bug-prone when making modifications in-place, no need to use grep when pulling values out, etc.

Comment: sorry i have to use grep even though your way is much better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can expand arrays in bash dynamically. you can use this snippet

`a=(); a[${#a[@]}]=${number}; echo ${a[@]}`

The first statement defines an empty array. with the second (which you can use in your while loop) you insert a value at last elment position + 1, due to `${#a[@]}` represents the length of `a`. the third statement just prints all elements in the array.

Comment: That's old syntax -- the much easier modern way to append to an array is just `a+=( "$value" )`.

Comment: I don't know if this answers the OP's question, but then, the OP's question isn't exactly clear (keeps using the word "array", but the code given shows no intent to work with actual shell arrays).

Comment: that's because i have no clue about array and thanks for the help :)